# Prove that if: $g: \omega_1\rightarrow\omega_1$ then for some $\alpha<\omega_1$: $\forall \beta<\alpha: g(\beta)<\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Prove that if $g: \omega_1\rightarrow\omega_1$ then for some $0<\alpha<\omega_1$,  $\forall \beta<\alpha: g(\beta)< \alpha$

How should I prove this theorem. I don't even know how to start

Comment: check the statement of the theorem, what you ask is not clear, for example, is $\omega_1$ a number or a set?

Comment: @Javi Given that ordinals and elementary set theory are tagged, I think it's reasonably clear what $\omega_1$ is (though I'm not going to go all in defending the level of context in this question).

Comment: @Javi $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, which is both a set and a (type of) number; this is standard notation in set theory.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I see, I agree with you and spaceisdarkgreen then, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We generally need to work with the things we have. So what do we have? we have two things:

The first thing we are given are well-orders. Ordinals are well-ordered. And well-orders invite recursion. The second thing, is that we are given $\omega_1$. Why not $\omega$? Why not $\omega+\omega$ or $\omega^3$?

Well, the function $g(n)=n+1$ is a function from $\omega$ to itself, but no $n<\omega$ satisfies this closure property. I leave it to you to find out why $\omega+\omega$, or $\omega^3$, or any countable ordinal, are not going to work either. There will be some function that avoids this condition.

So what is so different about $\omega_1$? Well. Two things, it is uncountable, and its cofinality is uncountable (which in this case means that it is regular). One of these properties should be used, therefore.

---

So let's try the recursion. Start with $\alpha_0=0$, and we should just try to approximate the closure point $\alpha$. What does that mean? Well, it means that we will construct a sequence, such that each ordinal is more and more closed under $g$.

So $\alpha_1$ will be the least ordinal such that $g(\alpha_0)=g(0)<\alpha_1$. This way, we will ensure that $g(0)<\alpha$.

Next, we need to make sure that $g(\beta)<\alpha$ for **all** $\beta\leq\alpha_1$. So $\alpha_2=\sup\{g(\beta)\mid\beta\leq\alpha_1\}$.

From here, you should be able to continue and define the sequence $\alpha_n$. Finally, take $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$, and prove that it is a closure point as wanted.

---

So what did we use about $\omega_1$? Not that it is uncountable, as much as it is closed under countable limits. Namely, that its cofinality is uncountable. As an exercise, find a function $g\colon\omega_\omega\to\omega_\omega$ which has no closure point.

Comment: This was probably the proof the OP was intended to give.. It's by far the most elementary way to see it.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of the statement you want to prove is (think about it, it's just standard logic):

$$\forall 0 < \alpha < \omega_1: \exists \beta < \alpha: g(\beta) \ge \alpha$$

So assume the above holds.
For definiteness we can define (by well-orderedness)  $g(\alpha) = \min \{\beta < \alpha: g(\beta) \ge \alpha\}$.

So $g: \omega_1\setminus\{0\} \to \omega_1$ is a regressive function.

Now apply the pressing down lemma (or Fodor's lemma), to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Using Fodor's lemma is really an overkill here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it was a standard theorem in my curriculum when we treated \omega_1$ so maybe it is for the OP too?

Comment: I had given my students this sort of exercise in the basic set theory course, where no mention of clubs, stationary sets, or Fodor's lemma is given. I would introduce the concept of cofinality, but even that was usually stretching the boundary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The form we got didn't mention stationary sets or clubs (these came a bit later) the conclusion we proved was that for $\beta$, $f^{-1}[\{\beta\}]$ was uncountable/unbounded. So not the "full force".. The above fact is often all that's needed e.g. in topological arguments involving $\omega_1$ in its order topology.

Comment: True. Still outside the context of a first course in set theory in many places, though...

Comment: See? I was right. The OP needs to use this to prove the pressing down lemma. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903302/pressing-down-lemma

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed. At least he's learning a version of the pressing down lemma, which is nice.